# For loop stop at first match IF?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So am I trying to filter a txt file with nodejs. This is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs')

let list = fs.readFileSync('./newmR.txt','utf-8').split('\r\n')

console.log(list.length)

for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){ 
   if(list[i].includes('has met failed') || list[i].includes('get captcha')){
       let index = list.indexOf(list[i])
       console.log(index)
       list.splice(index)
   }
}

fs.writeFileSync('./newmRfiltered.txt',list.join('\r\n'))
```

The point is it will read the txt file(bunch of emails) into a list then delete everyline that includes "has met failed" or "get capcha". The code stop at first match IF and exit the for loop. What happened?
The console output :

```
724 (length of the list)
74 (second console log)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are looping through the list, you are also decreasing its size so it gets smaller and as its length gets smaller you cannot loop further:

This is a better approch:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

let list = fs.readFileSync('./newmR.txt','utf-8').split('\r\n')

console.log(list.length)
let result = []
for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){ 
   if(!(list[i].includes('has met failed') || list[i].includes('get captcha'))){
       let index = list.indexOf(list[i])
       console.log(index)
       result.push(list[index])
   }
}

fs.writeFileSync('./newmRfiltered.txt',result.join('\r\n'))
```

Comment: NVM I figured it out. How stupid am I.... It has to be : list.splice(index,1)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `list.splice(index)` which should be `list.splice(index,1)`.

Plus you are changing the list.length inside loop when you are splicing it. So it will give you wrong answer anyway.

Comment: Okey I fixed it again by adding i--

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs')

let list = fs.readFileSync('./newmR.txt','utf-8').split('\r\n')

console.log(list.length)

let result = list.reduce((acc,item) => {
     if(!(item.includes('has met failed') || item.includes('get captcha'))){
       return [...acc, item];
     }
   },[]);

fs.writeFileSync('./newmRfiltered.txt',result.join('\r\n'))
```